# When searching for a value within a large field does it make a difference in efficiency if the field was sorted

Tags: r

I often have to search for a value in a field, the fields I search are large and I do this repetitively.  But often the fields I am searching for value in come into my data presorted.  Does it cost more to search for a value within an unsorted field compared to a sorted field? If so, do we have to tell R that the field is sorted before searching for what we want, and if yes how?

```
set.seed(4)
v1<- runif(1000000)
x <- v1[384932]
v2<- sort(v1)
```

We are searching for x in both vectors

Comment: Could you provide an example of what your "field" looks like and what code you currently use to search for values in that field?

Comment: sure, but its really any 2 vectors one random and the other sorted each with a 1000,000 elements would do the trick.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Package data.table optimizes this:

```
which(x == v1)
#[1] 384932

library(data.table)
DT <- data.table(v = v1)
DT[, ind := .I]
DT[v == x,]
#          v    ind
#1: 0.807405 384932

library(microbenchmark)
microbenchmark(which(x == v1),
               DT[v == x,])
#Unit: microseconds
#           expr      min        lq     mean   median       uq      max neval cld
# which(x == v1) 6507.923 6735.3560 6994.638 6930.145 7038.240 9693.825   100   b
#   DT[v == x, ]  813.030  849.9855 1082.465 1228.628 1258.347 1456.677   100  a
```

Quoting the 1.9.4 NEWS:

"`DT[column==value]` and `DT[column %in% values]` are now optimized to use `DT`'s key when `key(DT)[1]=="column"`, otherwise a secondary key (a.k.a. index) is automatically added so the next `DT[column==value]` is much faster. No code changes are needed; existing code should automatically benefit."

Answer (score 1):

I can't give you the technical details, but here's a benchmark showing a negligible performance difference (in base R):

```
set.seed(4)
v1<- runif(5e7)
x <- v1[384932]
v2<- sort(v1)

library(microbenchmark)

microbenchmark(
  unsorted = {which(v1 == x)},
  sorted = {which(v2 == x)})

#Unit: milliseconds
#     expr      min       lq   median       uq      max neval
# unsorted 263.2967 269.6947 273.4812 278.6712 871.6447   100
#   sorted 263.7483 270.8948 274.0171 278.2555 831.2782   100
```

Answer (score 1):

The efficiency of a "search" for an index by a numeric value isn't going to depend on the ordering of the values at all. The only time an extract operation (one using `"["`) will depend on some sort of ordering is with a named vector or a named list. It's hard to imagine that order matters when doing some sort of logical test. To get the most efficiency from access to named items, the gurus I trust suggest storing items in an environment so the indices can be hashed. http://markmail.org/message/pu3uib5muqjmz3l6?q=list:org%2Er-project%2Er-help+indices+hashing

Admittedly what follows is answering a different question. The help page `?sort` indicates that shell-sorts are done by default and that these are quicker in most instances than the alternate quick-sort method. My testing suggests that when sequences are known to be fully random that the quicksort is better. (But since I don't think you *should* be sorting things this is entirely beside the point.)

```
install.packages("rbenchmark")
library(rbenchmark)
rand <- sample(1:100000)
 benchmark( rs = { x <- sort(rand) }, rq={ x <- sort(rand, method="quick") },
            ss={ x <- sort(1:1000) }, sq={ x <- sort(1:10000, method="quick") })
 #----------
  test replications elapsed relative user.self sys.self user.child sys.child
2   rq          100   0.834  119.143     0.792    0.046          0         0
1   rs          100   1.583  226.143     1.539    0.047          0         0
4   sq          100   0.031    4.429     0.030    0.001          0         0
3   ss          100   0.007    1.000     0.008    0.000          0         0
```

That actually makes sense, once I get the combinations correct). Shellsort faster on sorted material, quicksort faster on random material.

Comment: If you know that you have sorted values, you don't need to scan the whole vector and can use binary search instead. That's what data.table does.

Comment: Btw. perfomance of `which.min` and `which.max` would be impacted (positively or negatively) by the sorting.

Comment: I've seen reports that efforts to find the "first" item using `which` can be optimized but I forget the exact incantations.